# is D3 looping through the whole array for each callback we set?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

It looks like d3 is looping through the whole array everytime a callback is set.

At first I supposed that calling functions like `attr()` or `each()` added these to a pipeline and that the whole pipeline was executed later and all at once.

I was trying to setup my code to dynamically process my data in the SINGLE loop used by d3, and I had just found `each()` which calls a function for each point.

The goal was to transform my points from a javascript object to a single value and avoid doing so for each callback or in a separated loop.

I tried it out and discovered this behaviour.

Here is a basic example:

```
d3.select(ref)
.selectAll("rect")
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("rect")
.each(function(d) { console.log(d); })
.attr("y", function(d) { console.log("attr y"); return 10; })
.attr("fill", function(d) { console.log("fill"); return "red";})
```

and here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7q3p2kah/1/

I was expecting to see this:

```
red
attr y
fill
green
attr y
fill
...
```

But I got:

```
red
green
blue
yellow
black
(4)attr y
(4)fill
```

The goal of all this experiment is to reduce the time needed to display my graphs.

Am I bound to use a separate loop to process my data or is there something I don't get?

It looks a lot like a `yes()` or `no()` question but I would be glad to see any explanation or alternative solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the `attr` functions within `each`:

```
...
.each(function(d) { 
    d3.select(this)
    .call(function(selection){console.log(d);})
    .attr("y", function(d) { console.log("attr y"); return 10; })
    .attr("fill", function(d) { console.log("fill"); return "red";}
})
...
```

more generally like here: https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/wns19k4d/

If I were you I would store the selected nodes in a `NodeList` or `LiveHTMLCollection` rather than using `d3.select(this)` and access them like `list[i]` or something, `d3.select` might be a bit slow in the long run.

Comment: About the second part of your explanation, can I just store the result of ```.append()```?

Comment: Append itself operates on the selection, it returns what the d3.selection returns, to access nodes within selection, in d3 v5 you can do selection._groups to access it, in d3v3 it is selection[0]. In v5 be careful because selections are not mutated, meaning that enter,update, exit do not silently change the original selection